# C: array or pointer causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For the two simple source files like below, there is a global array initialized in `a1.c`, and if it is referred as an array in `a2.c`, then the program runs OK. If it is referred as pointer (when `TEST` is defined), then segmentation fault occurs.

A local array and function `func()` are used for comparison. It runs OK if the argument is passed a pointer.

```
$ cat a1.c
char s1[] = "abc";

$ cat a2.c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef TEST
extern char *s1;
#else
extern char s1[4];
#endif

void func(char *s2)
{
    printf("s2: %s\n", s2);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("s1: %s\n", (char *)&s1); // ok for both cases
    printf("s1: %s\n", s1);          // Seg Fault if TEST is defined

    char s2[] = "123";
    func(s2);

    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall a1.c a2.c && ./a.out
s1: abc
s1: abc
s2: 123

$ gcc -Wall -DTEST a1.c a2.c && ./a.out
s1: abc
[1]    112651 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

Comment: Because, contrary to what uninformed people will tell you, arrays are not pointers?

Comment: Pointer are not arrays, (again).

Comment: Did someone mention that arrays are not pointers?

Comment: Also, `printf("s1: %s\n", (char *)&s1);` is UB in both the cases.

Comment: `ellipsis` (from function `printf`) can only take a subset of argument type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these declarations:

```
char a[1024];
char *a;
What happens when you write a[i] = j;?
```

For the former case, the compiler will just pick the address of a's contents, which, in arrays, is the address of the first element; scale i, and sum it to the base address. Then it will write the contents of the address where j is stored into that address.

For the latter case, it is quite different: the compiler has to check the memory location where a is stored, load the contents of that memory location, use THAT as an address, and write the contents of j into that address.

Now %s format specifier expects char*, Now you know why segmentation fault.. :)